# Create groups using a 30 day window in R

Tags: r

I have data to show a transaction date and the company id.

I want to number each transaction within a 30 day window starting from the first date in that window.

So for example for id 1, their window starts at 2023-01-04 and will run until 2023-02-03. Then the window will start again from the next transaction after that which is 2023-02-15 and then run until 2023-03-17 and so on.

The transactions within each window need to be numbered starting at 1 for each new window.

Example data below, the instance column shows the desired result.

df2 is as far as I have got, I just need to work out how to add the 30 day window, at the moment, its just numbering the rows per id without a time element.

```
library(tidyverse)
id<-c("1","1","1","1","1","1", "2","2","2")
date<-as.Date(c("2023-01-04","2023-01-15","2023-02-01","2023-02-15","2023-03-15", "2023-04-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-04-01","2023-05-03"))
instance<-c(1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,1)
df<-data.frame(id, date, instance)

df2<-df%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(instance2=row_number())
```

Can anyone suggest any updates to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here‘s one (admittedly verbose) approach to group the dates into 30-day windows.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, date) %>%
  mutate(days = as.numeric(date - lag(date, default = first(date))),
         days2 = 1 + cumsum(if_else(accumulate(days, ~if_else(.x >= 31, .y, .x + .y)) >= 31, 1, 0))) %>%
  group_by(id, days2) %>%
  mutate(instance = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-days, -days2)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  id    date       instance
  <chr> <date>        <int>
1 1     2023-01-04        1
2 1     2023-01-15        2
3 1     2023-02-01        3
4 1     2023-02-15        1
5 1     2023-03-15        2
6 1     2023-04-01        1
7 2     2023-01-01        1
8 2     2023-04-01        1
9 2     2023-05-03        1
```